# How to send data in body and queryparam by prototype.js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, javascript-framework

My Service (RESTful JAX-RS) is receiving values like the following.

```
public Response methodName(String content,
        @QueryParam("valueONE") String one,
        @QueryParam("valueTWO") String two,
        @QueryParam("valueTHREE") String three)
```

From the Ajax call I have to pass values to that service. To my scenario, I have tried like the below. It is not working to me.

```
try {
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method : 'post',
        postBody : {
            Object.toJSON(content),
            valueONE : one,
            valueTWO : two,
            valueTHREE : three,
        },
        onSuccess : function(response) {
            alert('Success Response' + response.responseText);
        },
        onFailure : function(response) {
            alert('Request has not been hit to the server.'
                    + response.responseText);
        }
    });
} catch (err) {txt = "_____ERROR_____\n\n";
        txt += "ERROR DESCRIPTION : " + err.message + "\n\n";
        txt +=" Click OK to continue."; 
        alert(txt);
}
```

I dont know how to pass values via body as well as queryparameter in Prototype.js. Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,
ArunRaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your request method is post, any parameters you set in the request will be sent in the body of the request. It is possible to also manually build in some querystring parameters in the URL you send to, although this is strictly not a correct way to send a POST (i.e. with a sidecar GET contained within it).

```
new Ajax.Request('path/to/server', {
  parameters: {
    foo: 'One',
    bar: 'Two',
    baz: 'Three'
  }
});
```

That's going to result in a set of POST variables [foo, bar, baz] being populated in the body of the request.

```
new Ajax.Request('path/to/server?boo=Four&blarg=Five', {
  parameters: {
    foo: 'One',
    bar: 'Two',
    baz: 'Three'
  }
});
```

That may, depending on the laxity of your server, result in the same POST along with a set of GET variables [boo, blarg] being populated by the querystring. On a PHP server, these are collated into the REQUEST global object, with same-name GET variables being overwritten by their POST equivalents, so you don't have to interrogate both sets of form data separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And really sorry for put up a question in a confusing way. I believe that is why you got diverted. Let me to make it clear. At my server side. I am having 3 queryString values and one string is without queryString. How to pass the with queryString and without queryString in a same Ajax call.

Comment: How to set variables as a value. for eg : var value1 = document.getElementById('result').value;  ...... parameters :{ foo : value1} .... Is it correct way of code. I think I am doing some mistake. That is why values are passed in the URL.

Comment: You could just use the same Ajax code above, but add method: 'get' to your request, like this: `new Ajax.Request('/url/on/server', {method: 'get', parameters: { foo: 'bar', baz: 'boo' }});`